# ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away - Broken db, table or is mysql broken?

Tags: mysql, database

On mysql 5.5.53 (innodb databases) under Debian 8

Another mysql newbie learning mysql the hard way. The really hard way. Any help provided would be fantastic. My site is offline which is a really big deal for me. The problem: I can't tell if I have a broken db, table or if mysql itself is broke.n mysql crashes with one db but not with another. I login into mysql using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Once in, I type

```
use drupal;
show tables;
```

Works great. I then type

```
use civicrm;
show tables;
```

I get

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
```

I then try

```
 mysqlcheck -u root --password civicrm
```

Which will begin to list all the tables of civicrm but it hits tables called log_civicrm_* after about 4 tables it crashes with

```
 Got error: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when executing 'CHECK TABLE ... '
```

Index files ib_logfile1 and ib_logfile0 are both rebuilt. I've set my.cnf to

```
key_buffer      = 512M
max_allowed_packet  = 64M
thread_stack        = 3M
thread_cache_size       = 8
```

I've tried to dump the database civicrm but it fails just as it starts. I can dump most all the tables except for a select few called log_civicrm_* I've tried to use

```
innodb_force_recovery=5
```

No change. The file /var/log/mysql/error.log reveals

```
170127 21:48:27 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.53-0+deb8u1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  
port: 3306  (Debian)
02:48:28 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
```

and

```
Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (7f23402d6f40): is an invalid pointer
Connection ID (thread ID): 9
Status: NOT_KILLED
```

Any attempts to drop a table from civicrm all fail with the 2006 error. What are my options here? Does the database need fixing, a table, or is some other thing broken and where do I go next to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Corrupt log tables. Causes MEGA-chaos for poor mysql. It's crash-a-roo anytime a CiviCRM table is used.

To resolve,

Find where the civicrm databases are stored. If on a typical *nix distribution and using mysql, likely /var/lib/mysql/civicrm

Shutdown mysql (service mysql stop)

Create a new directory (mkdir logtables), now move all the log tables into that directory (mv civicrm.log_* logtables)

Clear out the error.log files so you can see what is happening each time you start mysql. To do that cat /dev/null >/var/log/mysql/error.log (this assumes the mysql server log file is located at /var/log/mysql, which you'd check before issuing that command)

Start mysql (service mysql start)

If you do not have root privileges the OS will freak out when you attempt to move the log tables. Suggest elevating your privileges to root either using sudo (e.g. sudo mv civicrm.log_*) or su root, then go crazy but not too crazy. Remember, there's no undo in Unix/Linux. After starting mysql, check the mysql server's log file to see if it's happy again.